# Groovy: How to format output to ignore lines including "[ ]"?

Tags: bash, groovy

I wrote the following Groovy code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
String todayDate = new Date().format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
def rdbs = "aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier $dbname --snapshot-type automated --query DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='$todayDate'].DBSnapshotIdentifier".execute().text.eachLine {
retval.add(it.subSequence(4,it.length() ))
}
return retval
```

The idea is that the output will be added to an array but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
    at java_lang_CharSequence$subSequence$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at rds$_run_closure1.doCall(rds.groovy:8)
    at rds.run(rds.groovy:7)
```

So I've changed the script just to see if the output looks ok:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
String todayDate = new Date().format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
def dbname = 'dev-rds-2017-10-02'
retval=[]
def rdbs = "aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier $dbname --snapshot-type automated --query DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='$todayDate'].DBSnapshotIdentifier".execute().text 
println rdbs
```

When I run it, I get the following proper output:

```
[
    "rds:dev-rds-2017-10-02-2017-11-26-00-05"
]
```

But I want it to return only the "rds:dev-rds-2017-10-02-2017-11-26-00-05" line, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solves my issue:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
String todayDate = new Date().format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
def dbname = 'dev-rds-2017-10-02'
retval=[]
def rdbs = "aws rds describe-db-snapshots --db-instance-identifier $dbname --snapshot-type automated --query DBSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime>='$todayDate'].DBSnapshotIdentifier".execute().text.eachLine {
    if (!it.contains(']') && (!it.contains('[') ) )
        retval.add(it.replaceAll('\"','').trim())
}
retval.each {
    println it
}
```